# PHP skip iterate in array stdClass

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, stdclass

I´m iteration successfully through a large array that combines arrays and stdClass using the following code:

```
foreach ($arr as $A) {
        $THIS=$A->w->b;         
}
```

Here is an example of the array I'm iterating through:

```
Array
(
     [0] => Array
         (
             [w] => stdClass Object
              (
                 [b] => THIS
         )
     [1] => Array
         (
             [w] => stdClass Object
              (
                 [b] => THIS
         )
     [2] => Array
         (
             [w] => stdClass Object
              (
                 [b] => THIS
         )
     [3] => Array
         (
             [z] => stdClass Object
              (
                 [whatever] => NOT THIS
         )
)
```

I need to retrieve `THIS` values from `[x]` stdClass Object of each array; `[0]`,`[1]`,`[2]`,etc. But I do not need to retrieve values from `[z]` which has a different key.

Therefore when running the above code I successfully retrieve the desired `THIS`values, but I get repeatedly an error when iterating throughout the arrays that do not contain the stdClass object I desire:

`PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::`

What would be the simplest way through which can I set the iteration to skip certain undesired objects? or set it to skip if the desired object is not present?

Comment: What is `this` and `not this` ?

Comment: Because this is and example of a much larger array and it is simply what I want.

Comment: Your code and your example do not match at all. Why don't you write a code that would actually (try to) work on your sample data, so that we could see what is wrong with it?

Comment: It was an example. Is that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to check that the object parameters exist...

```
foreach ( $arr as $A )
{
  if( isset( $A['w'] ) )
  {
    $THIS = $A['w']->b;         
  }
}
```

Edit: You can also check further conditions

```
foreach ( $arr as $A )
{
  if( is_array( $A ) and isset( $A['w'] ) and is_object( $A['w'] ) and isset( $A['w']->b ) )
  {
    $THIS = $A['w']->b;         
  }
}
```